# Odoo 16 Error in loading XML record for Odoo report - "External ID not found in the system

Tags: xml, odoo-16

I have been trying to add a custom report to my Odoo installation, but I keep running into an issue. When I try to load the XML record for the report, I get the error message "External ID not found in the system: sale.report_noodverlichting".

This is my XML code for the report:

Action

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <record id="action_report_noodverlichting" model="ir.actions.report">
            <field name="name">Noodverlichting</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
            <field name="report_name">sale.report_noodverlichting</field>
            <field name="report_file">sale.report_noodverlichting</field>
            <field name="print_report_name">Noodverlichting</field>
            <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_sale_order"/>
            <field name="binding_type">report</field>
    </record>
    
</odoo>
```

Template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <record id="action_report_noodverlichting" model="ir.actions.report">
            <field name="name">Noodverlichting</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
            <field name="report_name">sale.report_noodverlichting</field>
            <field name="report_file">sale.report_noodverlichting</field>
            <field name="print_report_name">Noodverlichting</field>
            <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_sale_order"/>
            <field name="binding_type">report</field>
    </record>
    
</odoo>
```

Manifest

```
{
    'name': "Vupa_custom_fields",
    'depends': ['base', 'sale',],
    'category': 'Sales/CRM',
    'summary': 'Custom fields',
    'sequence': 42,
    'installable': True,
    'application': False,
    'license': 'LGPL-3',
    'data': [
        'views/res_partner.xml',
        'views/sale_order.xml',
        'data/klantnummer_sequence.xml',
        'report/report.xml',
        'report/noodverlichting.xml' 
    ]
}
```

I would like to create a report in the sale.order model with my one2many field i added to the sale.order application. My plan was to duplicate the Quotation PDF template but change the order lines with my one2many field i already have working in the sale.order view.